# How to test Active Directory authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I need to test Active Directory authentication with my MVC application but I don't have it running on my dev machine.

All I need to do is set permission on my controllers. I.E. The `ReportsController` can only be available for users that are members of the Reports groups on AD, so I did this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Reports")]
public class ReportsController : Controller
```

I also configured `web.config` to use Windows Authentication.

The problem is that I don't have a domain controller available to test it.

Is there any way I can simulate this AD environment or this is all I should do and this will work on the production server with AD?